# Samsung Gear Live not vibrating on notification

Tags: android, wear-os

I've made an app for the watch that vibrates when I click a button. That works great.
But when I try to create a notification that should vibrate when it appears, the notification appears, but there's no vibration.

The watch I have is a **Samsung Gear Live**.

The code I use to generate the notification is the following (On the watch)

```
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo128x128)
                    .setContentText("hello")
                    .setVibrate(new long[] {1000l});

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Vibration is not turned off in any setting.

So the question, why does not the wear vibrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The watch does not vibrate for notifications when the usb cable is connected for debugging.
Unplugging the usb cable enables vibrations again.